# Purrr, write_csv and naming things

Tags: r, tidyverse, geocoding

This has been a multi-step process so let me try and explain what is going on...

Am working on writing about 2000 files to csv.  This is a geocoding project, and decided to use tidygeocoder, which unfortunately results in a timeout error with some frequency, but it works well enough in my workflow.

The first process was to read the various files from csv, and to name them.  Just testing on the first 4 files so I get the process right.

Passing the 4 file names to read_csv, then set names, finally within each file there is a Combine_Address column, which I use to geocode.  Again no problems.  However, the final issue is naming.

Each of the four files should have a unique name but I consistently end with the error message

Error in stream_delim_(df, path, ..., bom = bom, quote_escape = quote_escape) :
invalid connection

which has resulted from both this...

- write_csv(path = here("excel_output", "geocode_output", paste0(names(.x),"_geocode.csv"))))

and

- write_csv(path = here("excel_output", "geocode_output", glue("{names(.x)}_geocode.csv"))))

```
# Loop geocode over .csv and export -------------------

files_to_read <- str_subset(list.files(here("excel_output", "csv_output"),
                pattern = ".csv$", full.names = T),
                ".csv")

file_names <- str_subset(list.files(here("excel_output", "csv_output"),
                pattern = ".csv$"),
                ".csv") %>% 
  str_remove(., ".csv")


files_to_read[1:4] %>% 
  map(~read_csv(.x)) %>%
  set_names(nm = file_names[1:4]) %>% 
  walk(~.x %>%
         geocode(Combine_Address) %>%
         write_csv(path = here("excel_output", "geocode_output", "_geocode.csv")))
```

The above code works well, but only outputs a single named file "_geocode.csv", but paste0 and glue have both yielded code errors.  At a loss about what to try now.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one `map` call itself. Try :

```
library(readr)

files_to_read[1:4] %>% 
  purrr::map(~read_csv(.x) %>%  
               geocode(Combine_Address) %>% 
               write_csv(sprintf('geocode_output_%s_geocode.csv', basename(.x))))
```

Comment: Excellent that worked very well!...though what does sprintf do?  I've seen it pop up a few times while researching the problem, but the help documentation is not very helpful

Comment: `sprintf` is similar to `paste0` but it is more concise I think since like `glue` you can specify a placeholder in between the string. You could write the same thing with `paste0` like `paste0('geocode_output_',basename(.x), '_geocode.csv')`